# one time notifications using react native firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I am using **react-native-firebase** to handle the device notification in my react native app. I am using subscribeToTopic() and unsubscribeFromTopic() api to get alerts on my device.

Problem is I want to give user options to set one-time or all-time notification. By default notifications are all time until user unsubscribe from it. I want to auto unsubscribe from topic if user set it as one time notification and app is in background. Is there any way to handle while my app is in background ?

Can any one help me how I can handle it in my react native code or any how?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How about simply calling `unsubscribeFromTopic()` after the user receives their first notification?

Comment: App is in background. Can I handle notification while app is in background ?. Can I get notified in the background app code that notification has been received ??

Comment: do you use `react-native-fcm`?

Comment: react-native-firebase . https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase

Comment: **"Can I handle notification while app is in background?"** , no but you can handle it when app open from the notification  using `getInitialNotification()` checkout the doc https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.2.x/messaging/reference/messaging#getInitialNotification

Comment: @Ali Is there a way to handle the one time notification ?? As with getInitialNotification() I will only be able to unsubscribe when user will open the app till then he will receive multiple notifications. I have notification which will come every minutes.

Comment: unfortunately I can't help you with this

Comment: Ahh okay..btw Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this on server side also. What you can do is unsubscribe a user form a topic after a message is sent to that topic. To do this you can use Firebase Admin SDK and in documentation it provides an example. You can give it a shot.